# Should simple comments that trigger an update to the question/answer be flagged as no longer needed?

Tags: support

I'm 0 for 2 on flagging comments as "It's no longer needed." on Sitecore Stack Exchange, and since there's nothing that suggests these are handled differently than Stack Overflow, nor are there comments on the declines, I need some guidance so I'm not wasting anyone's time. :)

According to the prompt and docs something should be flagged "It's no longer needed." if

> This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to this post.

I raised a flag today on the first comment on [ItemResolvers not working as expected](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7697/itemresolvers-not-working-as-expected) that's asking about what version the asker is using.

The question was updated to include the version, so it definitely seems the comment is outdated, and is now a slight distraction for someone reading through the question, answers, and discussions.

My first flag a year and a half ago was for [Datasource Subitems Items not being published in Sitecore 7.2](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/791/datasource-subitems-items-not-being-published-in-sitecore-7-2), which has a brief comment exchange about a possible duplicate post, currently showing as the third and fourth comments.

Two people happen to post the same link to a different question, and the person that got their comment in 21 seconds later does a second brief comment. Nothing wrong with that discussion, but four years later, those extra two comments are hiding six other comments and causing an extra click for someone who's skimming through.

Were these mistakes, am I missing something else, or does Sitecore Stack Exchange find value in/prefer not to remove these types of outdated/conversational comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should continue to flag comments, questions and answers, and if required make edits to titles, body and tags.

Sitecore Stackexchange (and Stackoverflow in general) is a community effort and as such relies on community members such as yourself to flag up issues or inconsistencies you may find. There is a too much content for the moderators alone to clean up, especially historical content.

I have cleaned up the specific comments you linked to. I am not sure why these were previously missed and will have to put it down to an oversight. Unfortunatelty for the 2nd questions, the comments still continue to fold up.

Thanks for highlighting, we will continue to monitor to ensure the flags are cleaned up appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for verifying I wasn't crazy re: the comments I flagged. :)